# how to use bundled react component without node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building a react project to deploy on apache server (no node on backend), lets say my component name is **FooComponent**, i have bundled it using webpack ( i have used babel on preset to parse the jsx and convert it to valid js code ), the problem which i am facing is how to use this component, in index.php i have code like this

```
<div id="container">

</div>
<!-- bundle contains my foo component -->
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script>

    ReactDOM.render( <FooComponent /> ,document.getElementById("container"));
</script>
```

but this code is going to fail since  it is jsx tag and we will get unexpected token `<` in the console,  how do i render this FooComponent properly? i dont want to use ReactDOM.render inside by my bundle.js file, i like to pass some data to this component ( the data would be arriving from php, if i assign it to js variable in index.php and refer that variable here i believe it might affect code readability )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `ReactDOM.render( <FooComponent /> ,document.getElementById("container"));` in plain javascript is:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(FooComponent, null), document.getElementById("container"));
```

You can produce this yourself using [babel's online tool here:](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.5&externalPlugins=)

Comment: So the only way is to manually parse the jsx tag myself and convert it to the js code?

Comment: `So the only way is to manually parse the jsx tag myself?` Not all, you can have a script do it. But without knowing the details of how your build process, it's hard for me to give specific recommendations. You're already using webpack and babel, so perhaps you can modify the webpack configuration.